# How to determine an objects type without iterating through all possible types?

Tags: java, object, types, iteration

I have a large collection of classes. These classes have similar properity names but with different values. For example, I have `Spearmen`, and `Swordsman`. These two classes have the same properity names but with different values for them. Now. Suppose I have another class. `Entity`. How can I call the class's constructor and specifiy which type of unit the entity should be, Without going through a chain of if statements to decicide whether the `object` is more specifically a type `Swordsman` or a type `Spearmen` or an ... Through all my classes.

I can make a simple runnable example but i'm not sure if it is necessary as I have explained myself above

Comment: Spearmen and Swordsman are different classes? do they inherit from the same base class?

Comment: @ShlomiHaver They are two different classes.

Comment: And they have the same properties?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following.  Could you put in some code or pseudo code?

Comment: @ShlomiHaver Yes the same properities

Comment: reflection is a possibility but I think a simple object-oriented design would be a more elegant solution.  Then you wouldn't necessarily need to know the type just a method that is shared between all/most of your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i can recommend you to do is to create an base class, lets call it hero

```
public class Hero
{
  public HeroType Type { get; set; }
  public int Power { get; set;}

  public Hero(HeroType type, int power){
      this.Type = type;
      this.Power = power;
  }

  ....
}
```

and then create an enum of hero types:

```
enum HeroType{
   Spearmen,
   Swordsman,
   ...
}
```

Every time you create a new hero you just need to specify his type like so

```
Hero swordsman = new Hero(HeroType.Swordsman,50)
```

this way you son't need to create multiple classes and you can save all your objects in the same collection because they all from the same base type.

And if you need a special Hero that has more properties you can create a new class that inherit from the `Hero` base class.

Comment: Thanks! If you could post a runnable example though that would be fantastic

Comment: @JammehCarr copy the code i wrote in my answer it should help you get started and then you can add your custom functionality depends on what you are working on.

Comment: Ok will do! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out the class name of an object you could try:

```
String className = variable.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 0):

java reflection API will give you methods to accomplish what you need.  Object.getClass()....

Comment: I know how to do it i just dont know how to do it without iterating through every class i have

Comment: @JammehCarr Use a switch stattement to continue your flow. Since we have generic informations on your issue, the easiest path would be get a String representation of the class name, and switch the alternative, and continue